# Is it possible for simple code to simulate a mouse click in another application?

Tags: delphi, click, mouse, simulate

Until now, I was using (in Windows XP with Delphi 7) this code with great success to create a rather simple program (to simulate) to click the mouse on any Windows application (not written by me in Delphi, of course):

```pascal
SetCursorPos(327,344);
{Simulate the left mouse button down}
Mouse_Event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,327,344 , 0, 0);
{Simulate the left mouse button up}
Mouse_Event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,  327,344, 0, 0);
```

Now, under Windows 10, when I use this code, the only thing my program does is move the cursor where I need to click, but no real click takes place.

I also tried this code, but also no real click:

```pascal
SetCursorPos(327,344);
ZeroMemory(@eu,sizeof(eu));
eu[0].Itype := INPUT_MOUSE;
eu[0].mi.dwFlags := MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
eu[1].Itype := INPUT_MOUSE;
eu[1].mi.dwFlags := MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
SendInput(2,eu[0],sizeof(TInput));
```

Can you help me with a code to do that click?

Also, maybe to simulate keyboard strokes like <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd> (select all)?

Now, I am using Delphi 10.3 Rio and Windows 10, and I AM LOST in the documentation. Could THIS be the problem?

> SendInput: This function is subject to UIPI. Applications are permitted to inject input only into applications that are at an equal or lesser integrity level.

Comment: "Could THIS be a problem?" Of course it could. Whether it is or not only you can know.

Comment: Try running the program that simulates the mouse click with full admin rights (run as administrator) and check whether this changes anything. Might be an issue with different integrity levels.

Comment: I tried using Delphi 10.3 and Windows 10, works very well. No issue at all.